# Ошибка: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, apache, сервер, centos, веб-сервер

Доброго дня!

Не сильно разбираюсь в настройках сервера. После попытки установки одного php модуля и перезагрузке сервера перестали отвечать все сайты.

Если в консоли набрать php -v, выдается следующая ошибка:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

PHP Fatal error:  [ionCube Loader] The Loader must appear as the first entry in the php.ini file in Unknown on line 0
```

OS сервера Centos 6
Подскажите, как это вылечить? Заранее, спасибо!

Comment: [ionCube Loader] The Loader must appear as the first entry in the php.ini file

Comment: @Etki поясните пожалуйста, что конкретно нужно прописать в php.ini ?

Comment: Попробуйте найти в файле `extension=ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so` и передвинуть его в начало. Или дописать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

это означает, что такого файла нет. возможно, он был переименован или заменен более новой версией (а в `php.ini` не были внесены изменения), возможно просто удалён.

поищите такой файл в каталоге `/usr`:

```
$ find /usr -name ioncube_loader\*
```

если найдёте его в другом каталоге (или под чуть другим именем), подправьте упоминание о нём в `php.ini`. найти упоминание (оно должно быть одно) можно, например, так:

```
$ grep 'zend_extension.*ioncube' /etc/php.ini /etc/php.d/*
```

после внесения изменений не забудьте перезапустить *apache*:

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: После удаления этих файлов и их упоминаний в /etc/php.ini apache и php начали нормально работать. Но после выполнения команды php -v предупреждение PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 все-таки осталось. Т.е. где-то остались не удаленные упоминания об этих файлах?

Comment: с помощью `$ php --ini` можно уточнить, какие файлы читаются в качестве инициализационных.

Comment: да, там осталось запись об этом файле. Спасибо, очень помогли!